# how to perform reveal view controller push controller programatically in SWRevealViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am building a navigation drawer like gmail. and I am using SWRevealViewController pod to handle this

from storyboard I can do it easily, If I want to move from side menu to a particular section, I can make it by using segue, control and drag from side menu to the destination view controller reveal view controller push controller

[image]

[image]

but now, I need to do it programatically, how to achieve this programatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you have segue with identifier then,

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "your segue identifier", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following in your action either in didSelect or under IBAction

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let sw = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sw") as! SWRevealViewController
        self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw
        let destinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "youIdentifier")
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationController!)
        sw.setFront(navigationController, animated: true)
```